# Equivalence of limits at (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am attempting to show that for any function $g: \Re^2 \rightarrow \Re$ where the limits $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} g(x,y)$ and $\lim_{y\to 0} lim_{x\to 0} g(x,y)$ both exist, they are equal to each other. My instinct is to take any sequence $(a_n, b_n)$converging to $(0,0)$ and then show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} lim_{n\to \infty} g(a_n,b_n)$=$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} g(x,y)$; however, I'm a bit confused as to how to go forwards.

Answer (score 1):

In fact we do not need that the second limit exists, we can prove it from the first. The statement that
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} g(x,y)=L\in\mathbb{R}$$
exists implies that any path in $\mathbb{R}^2$ terminating at $(0,0)$ will have the same limit. In particular 
$$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x,y)= L.$$
Before we can show this we must formalise what we mean by the "limit" of a function. The gold standard definition used is the epsilon delta statement which goes as follows:

---

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} g(x,y)=L$$ $$\iff$$ $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists\delta>0$ such that $|g(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon$ whenever $0<|(x,y)-(0,0)|<\delta$.

---

So then whenever $|x|< \dfrac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $|y|<\dfrac{\delta}{\sqrt{2}}$ we have $|(x,y)-(0,0)| = \sqrt{|x|^2 +|y|^2} < \delta$ and thus $|g(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon$. In words we might say "no matter how small you make $\varepsilon$ I can give you a $\delta$ such that whenever the point is within $\delta$ of the origin, $g$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $L$". This is precisely what we mean when we say "the limit of $g$ as $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$". *Note*: this implies that we have at least a small deleted neighbourhood $N$ around the origin, on which $g$ is defined.

The path in particular that you have specified with 
$$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x,y)$$
is $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,y) \rightarrow(0,0)$. let $x=0$ and $0<|y|<\delta$ (such that $(x,y)\in N$) then we have $0<|(x,y)-(0,0)| = |y| <\delta$ which implies $|g(x,y)-L|<\varepsilon$ (since $g\rightarrow L$ when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$) thus we have the claim:
$$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x,y)= L.$$